# Remove duplication from an array of objects

Tags: android, kotlin, duplicates, android-room

I have an object like below,

```
class LocationData{
 String time;
 String name;
 String address;
}
```

for this object i have created getter setter.

By using service i fill this above model and save into room database.
whenever user open my app i just update the room database data to server using API.
Now sometimes the time duplication occurred. How to remove the object from array based on time. time should be unique.

Comment: time is not unique, use GUID, autoincrement or sequence if you use Oracle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the extension function [`distinctBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct-by.html). If you have an array of `LocationData` objects called `allLocations` it would be

```
val distinctLocations = allLocations.distinctBy { it.time }
```

Note `distinctLocations` will be a List; if you want it to be an array, use `toTypedArray()`